# Word for groups of periods of time

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which would apply to the groupings of periods of time, for example:

Daily, Weekly, Bi-Weekly, Monthly, Annually etc

For example, "this task happens *daily*" where *daily* is ... the periodicity?

Comment: note you can, sometimes, use .. "period".  "We should repeat this over what period?"

Comment: No, *daily* etc. do not refer to periods. See my comment under @Josh61's answer about *frequency*. The title of this question does not correspond to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use [frequency](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frequency):

> - The number of complete cycles of a periodic process occurring per unit time.(AHD)

- daily frequency, monthly frequency etc.

Comment: Yes.  It is the *frequency*. It is **not** the *period*. This is analogous to the difference between *frequency* and *wavelength*. *Period* refers to the length of time between occurrences: 1 day, 2 weeks, etc. *Frequency* refers to how often the events occur: once every week (*daily*), every two months or twice a month (*bimonthly* - it's ambiguous), etc.

Comment: @Drew, there's some wiggle room to argue that *daily* etc is **can** be used to express a time period -- it is only the numerator of the calculation that yields frequency in expressions like "twice daily."  In that sort of construction, *daily* is not really the frequency.  The entire phrase is.

Answer (score 4):

I recently started seeing ['cadence'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cadence?s=t) used for this meaning.

> **noun**, Also, cadency
>
> 3 - the beat, rate, or measure of any rhythmic movement: 
>   The chorus line danced in rapid cadence.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

For example "The cadence of that meeting is fortnightly"...

But I only saw this for the first time a year or so ago, and not often since (though subjectively more and more as time goes on)

Comment: that's kind of deep, Marv!  for me it's only a cadence if the period is very regular.  so, "monthly" is not (it's 30, 28, whatever days).  "at exactly 24 minutes past every hour" is real cadence material.  "hourly" is not cadencish for me, becuase for me hourly means "some time within each hour, 24 times a day" rather than, well, necessarily in cadence

Comment: @JoeBlow Indeed, it did kind of take me by surprise when I first heard it (in a business context) but I do like the word, it has a kind of elegance...

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some variety to the discussion how about schedule

> The task may be *scheduled* Daily, Weekly, Bi-Weekly, Monthly, or Annually

Answer (score 0):

**Lapse** could also be used to describe the groupings in a slightly different way. "There is a day/month/year *lapse* between events. It is then understood that the events happen every day.

**Interval** could be used in a similar way. *It occurs at a daily interval*.